# What does unset value mean in CSS?

Tags: css, css-position, internet-explorer-11

I have a megamenu that is absolutely positioned, and as some of its parent elements need to have `position:relative`, I have to use `position:unset` on the direct parent. This works in Chrome and Firefox, however IE11 does not support `unset` or `initial`.

I can't simply remove the relative positioning from all of the parent elements as that will break other things, but I have to have the megamenu absolutely positioned relative to the page (fixed position does not work). Is there an alternative to `unset` that will work in IE11?

Comment: That doesn't work. My megamenu is supposed to be the width of the whole page, and when I remove the parent relative positions I get that, but when I set the parent to postiion:static it only takes the width of the parent element

Comment: You're right. There was another position:unset above it that was throwing it off. Static works

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`unset` means

> If the cascaded value of a property is the unset keyword, then if it is an **inherited property**, this is treated as `inherit`, and if it is not, this is treated as `initial`. This keyword effectively erases all declared values occurring

In your case, `position` is not an inherited property so it will always consider `initial`

> Each property has an initial value, defined in the property’s definition table.

For `position`, it's `static` So you can simply use `position:static` and it will behave the same as `position:unset`

---

Reference: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-cascade-3/

---

To make this more generic you have to either use:

- `property:inherit` if it's an inhertied propety
- `property:<initial_value>` if it's not an inhertied propety. Then you look at the property’s definition table to find the initial value.

[image]

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position