# Why can't values on the ::after pseudo-element be unset?

Tags: css, pseudo-element

Below is a very simple example to demonstrate the issue.

All paragraph elements are styled red, but then the content generated by `::after` should *not* be red anymore. Its color should be unset.

Why doesn't this work?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
p {color:red}
p::after { 
  content: " and after";
  color: unset;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>before</p>
</body>
</html>
```

With a property like `color`, at least a different value can be manually specified. But I've run into a case where I want to use `filter: brightness(1.2)` on an element but not allow that filter to affect the `::after` content.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56859256/8620333

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [this](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-unset-value):

> unset is a CSS value that's the same as "inherit" if a property is
>   inherited or "initial" if a property is not inherited

As `after` element is inherited from `p` element, `unset` will be as `inherit` and the color will be the red same as `p` tag.

Use `initial` instead

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
p {color:red}
p::after { 
  content: " and after";
  color: initial;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>before</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the helpful information. While `color: initial` does work in an `::after` pseudo-element, `filter: initial` does not. So there must be some additional rule for how inheritance is managed for the filter property. If anyone knows, please share.

Comment: I just found [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29249483/2454914) that addresses the part of my question about `filter`, so I think this case is closed. :-)